# AT sign in the nomenclature

Tags: symbols, nomenclature

I'm using the nomencl package.
I need to make an entry that contains the at symbol but entries containing @ don't appear in the nomenclature.

```
\usepackage{nomencl}
...
\nomenclature{abc@def}{Description.}
...
\printnomenclature{}
```

I've already tried \@, {@},"@",{"@"},\verb{@} etc

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: `@` is a `makeindex` special character so I expect you're getting an error from `makeindex` (check the `makeindex` transcript file). You usually need to escape it using `"@` (put a double-quote in front of it) but that may cause complications if the double-quote character is active (for example, if you are using `babel`). A MWE will tell us that.

Answer (score 4):

The character `@`, like `!` and `|` is special for MakeIndex, so it must be escaped if needed literally. The way to escape is by preceding it with `"`; `babel` doesn't seem to be a problem in this respect.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: nomencl
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % if you uncomment it it works the same
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

\begin{document}

x\nomenclature{abc"@def}{Description.}

\printnomenclature

\end{document}
```

The `arara` directives are just in order to make compilation easier. If you uncomment the `babel` loading, you'll see that `"` being a shorthand for German is not relevant for the problem at hand.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Since `@` is a special character, I usually just hide it from `makeindex` in a macro:

```
\newcommand\atsign{@}
\nomenclature{abc\atsign def}{Description}
```

If you want `@` to be taken account for during the sorting, you may use `"@`, as Nicola suggested in the comments, but since `"` might be active, I'd suggest using it only in the optional argument of `\nomenclature`:

```
\nomenclature[aabc"@def]{abc\atsign def}{Description}
```

Note the "nomprefix" here (by default `a`).